# AssertionError while trying to run tox command with Windows path

Tags: python, python-2.7, tox

I've some package and i'm trying to integrate `tox` with my `setuptools`.

I've installed `tox`, anc created the following `tox.ini` file:

```
[tox]
envlist = py27

[testenv]
commands = py.test
deps=   -r{toxinidir}/tools/pip-requires
        -r{toxinidir}/tools/test-requires
```

Then i'm `tox` and get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 2352, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 825, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 985, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1181, in install_python
    copy_required_modules(home_dir, symlink)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1119, in copy_required_modules
    dst_filename = change_prefix(filename, dst_prefix)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1084, in change_prefix
    (filename, prefixes)
AssertionError: Filename C:\Python27\Lib\os.py does not start with any of these prefixes: ['c:\\python27']
Running virtualenv with interpreter c:\python27\python.exe
```

I've tried to change my `PYTHONPATH`(windows) to `c:\...` pr `C:\...` but with no luck, any idea how to solve this issue?